# How to do fairly complex DTO validation in NestJS using Class validator

Tags: nestjs, dto, class-validator

I've done app setup correctly & everything works. Just need to know how to do the DTO validation as per requirement. Following is the DTO

```js
export class CreateFeedDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @Length(3, 100)
  @IsString()
  title: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @Length(5, 500)
  @IsString()
  body: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsInstance(File)
  attachment: File;
}
```

The following are the requirement

1. At least one of the fields is required
2. If any field is provided it must pass the validation mentioned in that field
3. All fields can be present
4. If all field is empty then show an error on only one field (msg like: `title, body and attachment can't be empty at the same time`)